# BMW 316i (2013) iDrive - How to add GPS and Nav software to BMWs iDrive

Tags: bmw, navigation, gps

I have a mid-option BMW 316i (2013). Which means that it has an iDrive display LCD in middle of the dash, which has Bluetooth/AUX/USB and other stuff but it does not have navigation and obviously no GPS. To add nav to it, is just a matter of software change and addition of GPS receiver. Easier said than done. Is it somehow possible to do it. If yes than how.

[image]

---

[image]

Comment: This was asked recently, but seems to have disappeared... but I think you are correct with easier said than done.

Comment: It's possible - although it's a bit more complex then "just" adding a GPS receiver and  flashing the software. Which headunit do you currently have? Also was your car manufactured before 07-2013 or after?

Comment: @motosubatsu I dont know the answer to these questions. And I just found out, it is a `2012 3 series F30 316i Dated: 26.11.2012`, it was imported and registered in my country in 2013. https://www.vindecoderz.com/EN/check-lookup/WBA3A1105DJ603201. If I contact my local BMW would they provide these service of changing